# Ambiguous implicit in Play

Tags: scala, playframework

I don't know where to begin debugging this. Play 2.3.5 with Slick and SecureSocial.

My routes were working fine until I wrote the first one accepting a parameter:

```
GET        /activity/            controllers.ActivitiesController.show(id: Int)
```

As soon as that route was added the compiler pointed to it and errors as such:

```
ambiguous implicit values: [error]  both method wrapJava in object HandlerInvokerFactory of     type => 
play.core.Router.HandlerInvokerFactory[play.mvc.Result]
[error]  and method wrapJavaPromise in object HandlerInvokerFactory of type => 
play.core.Router.HandlerInvokerFactory[play.libs.F.Promise[play.mvc.Result]]
[error]  match expected type play.core.Router.HandlerInvokerFactory[T]
```

Comment: `HandlerInvokerFactory[play.mvc.Result]` - why there is play.mvc.Result which is the java api ?

Answer (score 4):

Well, I am not sure whether you are in the situation mentioned by @rspencer .

I got the same error message in another situation:

In the `Controller`, when I try to make an `Action` unimplemented with the method `???` like this:

```
def test = ???
```

Then I open the browser and visit `http://localhost:9000`, a error message appear:

> ambiguous implicit values:
>    both method wrapJava in object HandlerInvokerFactory of type => play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory[play.mvc.Result]
>    and method wrapJavaPromise in object HandlerInvokerFactory of type => play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory[play.libs.F.Promise[play.mvc.Result]]
>    match expected type play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory[T]

If you are in this situation, jsut change the `???` to `TODO` like this:

```
def test = TODO
```

Revist `http://localhost:9000`, it's ok now.

Comment: Thanks! I ran into this exact same problem since I assumed `???` and `TODO` are synonymous. Although I can find the definition of [`???`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L230), I can't seem to find where `TODO` comes from. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't edit my previous comment, but I answered my own question. The definition of [`???`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L230) is baked into Scala, whereas [`TODO`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/d6c2673d91d85fd37de424951ee5ad9f4f4cce98/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Controller.scala#L33-L35) comes from Play.

Answer (score 0):

The routes file is not Scala and only compiles down to Scala. Consequently, the syntax you've used is incorrect. What you wrote:

```
GET        /activity/            controllers.ActivitiesController.show(id: Int)
```

should probably be something like:

```
GET        /activity/:id         controllers.ActivitiesController.show(id: Int)
```

and your `ActivitiesController` should then have:

```
class ActivitiesController extends Controller {
  def show(id: Int) = Action { ... }
}
```

Note the `:id` in the path component. This instructs the routes compiler to expect a string at that point in the URL path that can be implicitly converted to an Int. It then does the conversion and passes the integer argument to the controller's `show` method. You might be benefited from [reading the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaRouting)